# How I compare rows in pandas dataframe with a moving windows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, compare, row

I would to compare a group of a values between them with a moving window. I try to explain in a better way: I have a column on pandas dataframe and I would to test if 5 rows in a sequence are the same, but I would to do this examination in a moving window, that is to say I would to compare the row from 0 to 5, then the row from 1 to 6 and so on, in order to do certain changes. I would to know how I could do it in a better way than mine, because I used iterrows method.

my method:

```py
for idx, row in df[2:-2].iterrows():
        previous2 = df.loc[idx-2, 'speed_limit']
        previous1 = df.loc[idx-1, 'speed_limit']
        now = row['speed_limit']
        next1 = df.loc[idx+1, 'speed_limit']
        next2 = df.loc[idx+2, 'speed_limit']
        if (next1==next2) & (previous1 == previous2) & (previous1 == next1) & (now!=previous1):
            df.at[idx, 'speed_limit'] = previous1
```

Thank you for your patience. I would appreciate any suggestions. I wish you a great day.

Answer (score 0):

I want to post my solution based on numpy select and pandas shift, that is faster than previous.

```py
def noise_remove(df, speed_limit_column):
    
    speed_data_column = df[speed_limit_column]
    previous_1 = speed_data_column.shift(-1)
    previous_2 = speed_data_column.shift(-2)
    next_1 = speed_data_column.shift(+1)
    next_2 = speed_data_column.shift(+2)

    conditions = [(previous_1 == previous_2) &
                  (next_1 == next_2) &
                  (previous_1 == next_1) &
                  (speed_data_column == previous_1),
                  (previous_1 == previous_2) &
                  (next_1 == next_2) &
                  (previous_1 == next_1) &
                  (speed_data_column != previous_1)]

    choices = [speed_data_column, previous_1]

    df[speed_limit_column] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=speed_data_column)

    return df
```

If you have some suggestions, I'll appreciate. Have you a great day!